# GoogleAppsScript（GAS）で、Google共有ドライブの共有設定を取得したいです

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud, google-drive-sdk

GoogleAdminの
GoogleAppsScript（GAS）で、Google共有ドライブの下記共有設定を取得したいと考えております。

下記共有設定は、GoogleAdminの「監査と調査」→「ドライブのログイベント」でのフィルター条件にありますものです。
ーーー
属性：公開設定
値：
ウェブ上で一般公開
リンクを知っているユーザ
リンクを知っている対象グループ内のユーザ
外部と共有中
限定公開
対象グループ内のユーザ
内部で共有中
ーーー
これらの値はGASで取得する場合は、file.getSharingAccess()と何かほかの値をみて
判断しているように思いましが、詳しい方教えていただけませんでしょうか。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access?hl=ja
上記説明では、ログイベントにでてくるものとは括りが違うようです。

本来のやりたいこととしては、共有ドライブ内の、外部と共有されているファイルを絞りだしたいというものになります。
他に適切な方法があればご教授くださいませ。